# SQL/ Return MIN values of multiple rows

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the minimum value of open, across multiple rows of year. This is from app.mode.com and the site only says SQL, not sure which version

```sql
SELECT year, open
FROM tutorial.aapl_historical_stock_price
WHERE open = 
(
    select MIN(open)
    FROM tutorial.aapl_historical_stock_price
)
```

When I use the code above, the result is
[Table result vs actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiirn.png)

| Year | Open |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 0 |
| 2000 | 0 |
| 2000 | 0 |

What I'm trying to get is

| Year | Open |
| --- | --- |
| 2002 | 0 |
| 2001 | 0 |
| 2000 | 0 |

Can someone help point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: This looks wrong. If there are rows with years 2001 and 2002 and open = 0, then your query would get them. And if there aren't, why would you want them in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select year and get the min by grouping each year as following:

```
select 
    year
    , min(open) as <desired_alias>
from your_table
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried doing the min(open) before but the query never fired. I wonder if it's because I didn't do the group or order by

Comment: yeah, `group by` is the key here. `order by` is just for the user to observe the data easier - i.e. makes life easier by a lot.